# Showing Dialog after button click

Tags: python, pyqt

I have been following this tutorial: https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/04/16/pyside-standard-dialogs-and-message-boxes/ in order to make one of my buttons show a notification message box after the dialog has been clicked. The problem is that the code doesn't show the dialog box at all. Here is my code with what I have attempted so far and the stack trace.

```
# parsing Information Message Dialog
    def data_parsed_notification(self):
            """
            Show the information message
        """
            QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "Data Has Been Parsed!")


    # Data Parsing Functions!!!

    # Canonical Addresses button function
    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(True)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification())
```

Stack Trace

```
QtGui.QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "Data Has Been Parsed!")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMessageBox'
```

Code now at present

```
# Data Parsed Dialog Box
    def data_parsed_notification(self):
        msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(self)
        msgBox.setWindowTitle('Information')
        msgBox.setIcon(QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Information)
        msgBox.setText('Data Has Been Parsed!')
        msgBox.show()

    # Canonical Addresses button function
    def select_canonical_data(self):
        os.system('CanonicalAddressesParser.py')
        self.generate_canonical_report.setEnabled(True)
        self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification())


Stack Trace 

TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QMessageBox(QWidget parent=None): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
  QMessageBox(QMessageBox.Icon, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.NoButton, QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=Qt.Dialog|Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'
```

Comment: I have a working code, something like this:
```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QMessageBox

QMessageBox.information(parent, title, message)
```

can you try to do import like mine?

Also, you have a different indentation. Perhaps you can fix that also.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below and it will work for you.

```
self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)

def data_parsed_notification(self):
    msgBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox()
    msgBox.information(self, Message', 'Data Has Been Parsed!')
```

Comment: I am using PyQt5 . It is telling me this: msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox(self)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'QMessageBox'

Comment: I have used your code. Still does not work. I have given a snippet of the way my code looks at the moment

Comment: what error do you get after replacing the function?

Comment: I have the stack trace included above in my edited code

Comment: A TypeError:   TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:

Comment: msgBox.information(self, "Message", 'Data Has Been Parsed!')
TypeError: QMessageBox.information(QWidget, str, str, QMessageBox.StandardButtons buttons=QMessageBox.Ok, QMessageBox.StandardButton defaultButton=QMessageBox.NoButton): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Ui_MainWindow'

Comment: i think something is wrong with your code. Try to replace `self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification())` with `self.canonicalAddressesButton.clicked.connect(self.data_parsed_notification)`

Comment: I made the change as you suggested. No compiler error now. But it does not do anything.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166248/discussion-between-and3r50n-1-and-greencoder90).